# How to make refrence to field in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

How to mak refrence from field to another sheet field in Google Sheet?

So, I have  product position I need to make to sheet of factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en).

example:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[your sheet's id]/edit?usp=drivesdk","Sheet1!G2")
```

Comment: And how to go by link?

Comment: If you want to jump to the sheet by link, use [HYPERLINK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en).